# Replace Url value in textbox with regexp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a server size image stream where you pass "fileid", width and height to and it streams an image to client. I'm using CKEditor, and would like to add jquery function that changes it's url when height or width changes in the textboxes.

As you see here on the pic its a specific format:

[image]

/Content/Image/{digit}/{width}/{height}  rest is optional in string.

Lets say id's of them textboxes are "txtwidth" and "txtheight", how would you add jquery functionality to it that replaces width and height in url textbox, and only if it matches string starting with /Content/Image/{digit}/{width}/{height}?

Thanks in advance

/Lasse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily by using regexp to match the string and to replace the corresponding parts. As you mentioned that you'd want to do this with jQuery I am assuming you have jQuery already on your site, but if you don't I wouldn't recommend adding it for this.

Instead of explaining further what to do, I've pasted the code below and commented each step, which should make it quite clear what's going on:

```
// bind onchange and keypress events to the width and height text boxes
$('#txtwidth, #txtheight').bind('change keypress', function(){

    // define the regexp to which to test with, edit as needed
    var re = /\/Content\/Image\/([0-9]+)\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\//,
        // store url and its value to a variable so we won't have to retrieve it multiple times
        url = $('#url'),
        val = url.val();

    // test if regexp matches the url
    if (!re.test(val)) {
        // doesn't match
         return;    
    }

    // we got this far, so it did match

    // replace the variables in the regexo
    val = val.replace(re, "/Content/Image/$1/" + $("#txtwidth").val() + "/" + $("#txtheight").val() + "/");

    // put it back into the input field
    url.val(val);

});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/wsAcq/

Comment: Better implementation than mine: good idea to take key press event into account, and to use one code for the two inputs.

Comment: Worked great when I used the .live instead of .bind :) tyvm :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that the URL field has the HTML id "fileUrl". The regular expression equivalent to its value is:

```
/^\/Content\/Image\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/
```

Here is a quick proposal (not tested and not optimized at all):

```
$("#txtwidth").change(function()
{
   var value=$("#fileUrl").val();
   $("#fileUrl").val(value.replace(/^\/Content\/Image\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/, "/Content/Image/$1/"+$("#txtwidth").val()+"/$3"));
});

$("#txtheight").change(function()
{
   var value=$("#fileUrl").val();
   $("#fileUrl").val(value.replace(/^\/Content\/Image\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/, "/Content/Image/$1/$2/"+$("#txtheight").val()));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i was going to suggest /(\d+)/g

```
<div id="replace_this">/Content/Image/56/1024/768</div>

var newWidth = 2048;
var newHeight = 384;
var matches = $('#replace_this').html().match(/(\d+)/g);
newHTML = $('#replace_this').html().replace(matches[1], newWidth);
newHTML = newHTML.replace(matches[2], newHeight);
$('#replace_this').html(newHTML);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qpmuT/

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest a similar approach as [Niklas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8678839/990877) (before I was interrupted by something important, or possibly a squirrel). So go with that (and `+1` from me).

A couple of points, though:

- Validate the contents of the `width` and `height` fields. Or at least use `parseInt`. Otherwise, if the user enters a non-digit character, the regular expression will stop matching...
- Match on `[0-9]*` instead of `[0-9]+`. The latter would break the regex if the user left a field empty. Of course, doing `val = parseInt(...) || 0` would fix it as well.

In other words, I'd do something like this:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/j8dT9/

```
var re = /\/Content\/Image\/([0-9]*)\/[0-9]*\/[0-9]*\//,
    url = $('#url'),
    val = url.val(),
    width = parseInt($("#txtwidth").val(), 10) || 0,
    height = parseInt($("#txtheight").val(), 10) || 0;

if (re.test(val)) {
    val = val.replace(re, "/Content/Image/$1/" + width + "/" + height + "/");
    url.val(val);
}
```

Also, in case the path (`/Content/Image/`) might change in the future, you could use this more general regex: `/^\/(.+)\/([0-9]*)\/[0-9]*\/[0-9]*\//` and let the replacement string start with `/$1/$2/`. (See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/j8dT9/1/).)

Finally, I wouldn't bind to `keypress`. Aside from possible side effects in some browsers (like the `change` event not being handled), there is a UX concern. Most users are used to input widgets handling their input on `blur`, because their native apps work that way. Besides, many users look at their keyboard when typing numbers (numpads are getting rare, these days).